# Synchronizing between appdomains using named mutex

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to sync between 2 appdomains, but can't get this to work.

I have this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (Mutex m = new Mutex(true, "Global\\m"))
    {
        AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ad");
        var dllName = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath;
        ad.CreateInstanceFrom(dllName, typeof(Consumer).FullName);

        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        m.ReleaseMutex();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and

```
public class Consumer
{
    public Consumer()
    {
        //var createdNew = false;
        //Mutex m = new Mutex(false, "Global\\m", out createdNew);
        Mutex m = Mutex.OpenExisting("Global\\m");
        m.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

I expect "Done" to be printed after 4 seconds, but it gets printed right away.

I've tried creating mutex in consumer with constructor and using OpenExisting - makes no difference.
Don't think naming mutex "Global" makes any difference in this case, but tried it too.

Gotta be missing something, and I can't figure out what.. help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mutex is owned by a thread and they are recursive, i.e. can be entered again on the same thread. Use a mutex to exclude *other* threads from accessing the same resource simultaneously. All you've done is create a mutex owned by the calling thread and then waited on it. Since the thread already owns the mutex, `WaitOne` immediately returns.

To see a delay you would have to call `OpenExisting` and `WaitOne` on another thread. For demonstration purposes, you could try this:

```
public Consumer()
{
    Task.Run(() => {
        Mutex m = Mutex.OpenExisting("Global\\m");
        m.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    });
}
```

Comment: Right, same thread Id. This explains. There must be a way to sync between appdomains, though, without spawning new threads? I imagine monitors wouldn't work either.

Comment: Yeah, this would work. I still wonder though if there's a way to do appdomain synchronization.

Comment: @Eugene What do you mean by sync between AppDomains? If there is only one thread, there is no synchronization to worry about. Threads need to synchronize not appdomains.